# PHP variables inside MySQL statement are empty on one page but not another

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have this script working perfectly when opening the file on its own [**here**.][1]

But when I embed it in my website it fails on the third MySQL statement.

I have done `var_dumps` on all of the variables and pinpointed it to be `$bridge_note` or `$tuning_capo` that is empty.

I have treid enclosing the variable with `".."` and `''` and `""` and without any quotes and also `<? echo $bridge_note; ?>` but every time the error is the same

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT ,8' at line 1
```

I have fixed this issue now. It was the 2 global variables $tuning_capo and $chrd_tn that were not passing over to the function.

Instead of using
        global $chrd_tn, $tuning_capo;

I used this
                        if (isset($page_tuner)) {
                        $GLOBALS['chrd_tn'] = $page_tuner;
                        } else {$GLOBALS['chrd_tn'] = 'C#G#C#FG#C#';}
                        $GLOBALS['tuning_capo'] = '0';

```
                    if (isset($_GET['capo']))
                    $tuning_capo = $_GET['capo']; 

                    if (empty($tuning_capo)) {
                        $tuning_capo = 0;
                    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do.<br />
send this variable from one page to another?<br />
How do you call this function?<br />
Did you tried to use sessions?

Comment: The function is being called using the code I have to added to the end of my initial question. I have not tried sessions as I have never had success with learning them.

Comment: Eventually the variable will be taken from the current url the script resides at.

Comment: i see no call to the function chords() in the latter code

Comment: Sorry I had the call in another file. I have added the chords() function call to the end of the latter code

Comment: WarmWhisky, it is proper to answer your own question and accept it rather than update your question to include the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given how the error message has arisen, I would suggest its $tuning_capo that is the problem. You need to find where $tuning_capo's value is (or where is should be) set and then carry on from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply MikeyB. If I change $tuning_capo to 0 the error is then 'LIMIT 0,8' at line 1
After that, if I change $bridge _note to 28 it works. but I need it to be a variable to make the function work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`$bridge_note` is not defined anywhere in the function.

To help you spot such errors, PHP have to be run with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` set somewhere at the top.

Comment: Thanks for that Col. I have added it, it did show me that some of my arrays were not already defined, but upon fixing them it doesn't fix my SQL error on the embedded page. I can't understand at all why this is happening when I am using variables in the same way in previous SQL statements. I'm lost on this. Have been stuck on it for over 24 hours now.

Comment: your second query doesn't return any rows. thus you have $bridge_note undefined

Comment: it is probably not the same. post the error. and the query you are feeding to mysql. it is always helps

Comment: Isn't %bridge_note defined here already though?$bridge_note = ($row["note_id"]);

Comment: I realized now that calling the two globals $chrd_tn and $tuning_capo are the ones that are undefined in the function. I have defined outside of the function. Maybe this is the problem? I need a way to get them into the function.